# Use batch file timeout without echoing command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm fairly new to batch scripting but reasonably competent with programming in general. I'm currently calling a perl script from a batch file and am displaying the result from the perl script in the Windows command window for 10 seconds before exiting the command window.

I'm using the command

```
timeout /t 10 /nobreak
```

which is then also printed to the command window after the result of the perl script.

Is there any way to prevent this so that I just see the result of the perl script and then see the timer counting down?

I understand I can append '> NUL' to my timeout command to suppress the countdown timer but this isn't what I want to do. I just want to prevent what I see as a line of code printing to the command window. If this can't be done, it's no problem, I'll live with it. But if I can remove it I'd like to.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to avoid echoing one command, prefix it with `@`:

```
@timeout /t 10 /nobreak
```

You can disable echoing at all with command

```
echo off
```

Normally, you put

```
@echo off
```

at beginning of batch file, so commands are not outputed.

Comment: Despite the comment here
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file#Explanation
that '@ symbol at the start of any line prevents the prompt from displaying that command as it is executed', this does NOT work for Timeout. The post below by user6024091 to pipe the output to >nul DOES work however.

Comment: @DavidCarr `@` prevents command echoing, not command output. `>`, `2>` and `|` are used for output handling, but this not the question in this case.

Answer (score 19):

Try doing,

```
timeout /t 10 nobreak>nul
```

Comment: From the question: *I understand I can append '> NUL' to my timeout command to suppress the countdown timer but this isn't what I want to do.*.

Comment: For me, piping >nul to the timeout command effectively suppresses the message, e.g.
Waiting for 5 seconds, press a key to continue ...43210

Answer (score 0):

The way i do it is like this.

```
::silent timeout
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('
timeout /t 10 /nobreak 2^>Nul
') do echo | break
```

a simple one liner can be `timeout /t 10 /nobreak >nul`